# Convert Pandas dataframe to csv string

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an example of what I am trying to get:

I have:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0, 1], 'B' : [1, 6]})
```

My goal is:

```
',A,B\n0,0,1\n1,1,6\n'
```

I can achieve this with lazy and horrible:

```
df.to_csv('temp.csv') # create unnecessary file
body = open('temp.csv').read()
```

Also `to_string()` methods looks very promising; however, the best I can come up with is this:

```
body = df.to_string()[1:].replace('  ', ',') + '\n'
```

This does not create an unnecessary file, but seems sloppy and perhaps not very reliable.

Am I missing a simpler solution?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
In [10]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0, 1], 'B' : [1, 6]})

In [11]: import io

In [12]: s = io.StringIO()

In [13]: df.to_csv(s)

In [14]: s.getvalue()
Out[14]: ',A,B\n0,0,1\n1,1,6\n'
```

Comment: -1 as it is an overkill (maybe it was from a previous version of pandas). But in latest if no `path_or_buf` is provided the result is returned as a string. See answer below.

Answer (score 186):

The simplest way is just to not input any filename, in this case a string is returned:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [0, 1], 'B' : [1, 6]})
>>> df.to_csv()
',A,B\n0,0,1\n1,1,6\n'
```

Comment: If you are using a series, you need to wrap it in a dataframe constructor: `pandas.DataFrame(series).to_csv()`.