# adding a comment with "to_csv" using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm saving a dataframe with the method `to_csv`, and the output is like that:

```
2015 04 08 0.0 14.9
2015 04 09 0.0  9.8
2015 04 10 0.3 23.0
```

but I need to make some modifications to this output, I need to add a comment and a column with a constant value and the same size that the others columns. I need to obtain an output like this one:

```
#Data from the ...
#yyyy mm dd pcp temp er
2015 04 08 0.0 14.9 0
2015 04 09 0.0  9.8 0
2015 04 10 0.3 23.0 0
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Why not just `open` the file and write to it?

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your dataframe and your script ?

Comment: Is it pandas data frame? pandas `to_csv` has option `header`, which is default True, so your columns names should be written automatically

Comment: As @MicahSmith says, write the CSV first, then use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5917395/2071807) to add the comment to the top of the file.

Comment: Good morning, this is the only way I found:                                                                                 <pre><code>  line= "#GEO \n#lat    long    level   date    time    value \n#DATA\n"                                                                                         with open(Filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(line)
df1.to_csv(auxiliar, index = False, sep='\t', float_format='%.6f', header = False)
    with open(nombreFichero, 'a') as f:
         with open(auxiliar, 'rb') as g:
              shutil.copyfileobj(g, f)  </code></pre>

Answer (score 8):

The easiest approach is to add the comment first and then append the data frame. Two approaches to this are given below, and there is more info in [Write comments in CSV file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233496/write-comments-in-csv-file-with-pandas).

#### Read in test data

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in the iris data frame from the seaborn GitHub location
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
# Create a bigger data frame
while iris.shape[0] < 100000:
    iris = iris.append(iris)
# `iris.shape` is now (153600, 5)
```

#### 1. Append with the same file handler

```
# Open a file in append mode to add the comment
# Then pass the file handle to pandas
with open('test1.csv', 'a') as f:
    f.write('# This is my comment\n')
    iris.to_csv(f)
```

#### 2. Reopen the file with `to_csv(mode='a')`

```
# Open a file in write mode to add the comment
# Then close the file and reopen it with pandas in append mode
with open('test2.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('# This is my comment\n')
iris.to_csv('test2.csv', mode='a')
```