# Python - writerow and dataframe to csv

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

Need some help on python insert to csv.
Would like insert info and data frame to to csv.
After insert info with writerow, when insert data frame into csv, there was missing some header from data frame.

Correct header without : writer.writerow(info)
[image: Correct Header from data frame]

Wrong data frame header with : writer.writerow(info)
Missing 'No' to 'Billno' from data frame.
[image: Missing header from data frame]

```
df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
info = ['Date From:','',fromdate,'','To',todate]
with open('C:/my_csv/'+reportname+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
   writer = csv.writer(file)
   writer.writerow(info)
   folder_path = r'C:/my_csv'
   file_type = r'/*csv'
   files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
   max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
   df.to_csv(max_file, index=True, index_label="No", header=True)
```

Comment: there are mismatched file paths `'C:/my_csv/'`, `r'C:\my_csv'` and you're writing to a different files

Comment: Just few header from the dataframe was missing. Other data from dataframe inserted.

Comment: Your expected output does not match your `info` variable. What is `Header 1`, `Header 2`,.. ? Also, why you're using empty strings ? And what's the output of `print(df.shape)` ? Can you share a minimal reproducible example of your `df` (_just a few rows_) ?

Comment: Hi @Timeless i have added 2 image. 
1 was correct header without : writer.writerow(info)
2 was wrong data frame header with : writer.writerow(info)

Comment: I don't understand what information is missing.  Your `info` is present, but you are not writing your dataframe to the CSV file you opened.  What's the `max_file` thing about?  Why not just pass `file` to `df.to_csv`?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts The data frame write in the csv file, but there was missing from 'No' to 'Billno'
The max_file was write to the latest csv file inside the folder.

Comment: That's probably because you're writing to the same file through two different handles.  pandas writes the CSV, then your "writer.writerow" overwrites the first few bytes of the file.  You need to share the file HANDLE, not the file name.

Comment: @TimRoberts May i know which file handle you mention that i need to share? csv.writer?
Yes the csv.writer overwrite few bytes of the file. may i know how to avoid it to overwrite?

Comment: You open the file.  You call the handle `file`, and you pass it to the csv writer.  You then give the filename string to pandas.  It then has to open the SAME file again, getting a different file handle.  The two are not synchronized.  If you just pass the `file` variable to `df.to_csv` instead of a file name, it will write to the file you have already opened, and things will stay synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233496/write-comments-in-csv-file-with-pandas) as a template you could try something like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Index" : [0,1], "A": [1, 1], "B": [2, 2], "C": [3,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index("Index", inplace=True)

date_a = 19022023
date_b = 20022023

f = open('foo', 'a')
f.write(f"Info_1, {date_a}, Info_2, {date_b}\n")
df.to_csv(f, sep=",", header=True)
f.close()
```

```
>>> more foo

Info_1, 19022023, Info_2, 20022023
Index,A,B,C
0,1,2,3
1,1,2,3
```