# Set of dataframe hashes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hash, set

I want to create a set with dataframe hashes so that i can check if new dataframes have been already processed in my program and not repeat the same process.
It would be something like this:

```
explored = set()
while True:
      df = generate_df()
      if df in explored:
            continue
      do_something(df)
      explored.add(df)
```

I know that the df object is not hashable, thats why the code above doesn't work. However i don't need to store the df object in the set but some value that prevents me to process a new df that it is equal, sort of a value to compare.

Comment: what about hash(df.to_csv()) . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231605/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-string

Comment: thanks! That works